# How to enable/disable components in jsf/icefaces?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am looking for how to enable and disable the icefaces components based on the user login ?
For example:

if login as admin i need to enable the come more components and login as user, disable some components as well as add some other components in one page ? How to do this function in jsf/icefaces ?

These two enable and disable in one page .

I appericate your suggestions.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `rendered` attribute. It accepts a boolean expression. Add a method to the `User` entity like `isAdmin()` or `getRole()` and let the `rendered` attribute intercept on that.

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{user.admin}">
    Will be displayed when user.isAdmin() returns true.
</h:someComponent>
<h:someComponent rendered="#{user.role != 'ADMIN'}">
    Will be displayed when user.getRole() (String or enum) does not equal ADMIN.
</h:someComponent>
```

For the case you're interested, here are some more examples how you could use boolean expressions in EL.

JSP-compatible syntax:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue > 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue == null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue != 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!bean.booleanValue && bean.intValue != 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.enumValue == 'ONE' || bean.enumValue == 'TWO'}" />
```

Facelets-compatible syntax with some [XML-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359899/using-in-el-results-in-error-the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the/13360064#13360064) EL operators like `>` and `&` changed:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue gt 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue eq null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue ne 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{not empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{not bean.booleanValue and bean.intValue ne 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.enumValue eq 'ONE' or bean.enumValue eq 'TWO'}" />
```

Comment: did JSF2 no longer allow the use of `&&`, because it give me this `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference`. However, if I use the keyword `and`, then it works

Comment: @Harry: Oh sorry, that was the JSP style. In XML (XHTML, Facelets) you need to escape XML entities. The `&` is one of them. Yes, `and` is the right keyword. For the remnant, [here's an overview](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaik).

Comment: @ThankPharm Sorry, what do you mean by your first comment? Is using && not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

In ICEfaces for controls that has disabled property use:

```
<ice:inputText disabled="[true/false]"/>
```

**Example**

I used this in my code:

```
<ice:inputText disabled="#{ABMUsuario.accion!='3'}"/>
```