# JSF: Is it possible to create a custom converter for this

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, converters

I am using JSF 2.0 btw
I have an attribute `X` type Integer, that has default value 0. In my JSF page, I create a component that I want it to be disabled if `X` is 0, and enabled otherwise.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{X}"/>
```

and I got this error

```
Cannot convert 0 of type class java.lang.Integer to class java.lang.Boolean
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "entity type Interger"

Comment: uhmmm, an attribute `X` type Integer, that what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague and ambiguous. I don't see how a converter is useful here. A converter is mere to convert between a non-standard type and `String` type (the standard types for which EL has builtin conversions (coercions) are primitives, `Number` and `Boolean`). Also, I think that you actually meant "rendered in component tree" when you said "disabled" and "enabled".

In a nut, you basically want `<h:someComponent rendered="#{X != 0}" />`.

Can't you just do that?

Comment: Also; a few components have the attribute disabled, used the same way.
I would suggest keeping a boolean variable for enabled/disabled, though: `<h:commandButton disabled="#{not entityBean.enabledButton}" />`

Comment: The components representing HTML form elements indeed have that. But that was not *that* obvious from the question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know you can do it like that, I originally have it as `rendered=#{X}` and hoping that it would behave like `C` where anything 0 is false, and true otherwise. But it gives me an error, said that it cant convert from 0 to type boolean, so I thought I need some kind of custom converter here. It works great now, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. For another examples of boolean expressions in EL see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466289/how-to-enable-disable-components-in-jsf-icefaces/3466918#3466918).