# Using && in EL results in error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: jsf, el, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I'm trying to use a conditional expression in an el expression used in jsf, but it does not work.

```
<h:outputText value="#{(sel.description !=null) && (sel.description !='') ? sel.description : 'Empty description'} - "/>
```

but it does not work, the compiler says:

> Error Traced[line: 118] The entity name must immediately follow the
>   '&' in the entity reference.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You seem to be using Facelets (which is perfectly fine). It's however a XML based view technology. Everything which you write in Facelets has to be syntactically valid XML. The `&` is in XML a special character denoting the start of an [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) like `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&#160;`, etc.

If you would like to represent the `&` as-is in XML, then you'd have to replace it by `&amp;`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{(sel.description !=null) &amp;&amp; (sel.description !='') ? sel.description : 'Empty description'} - "/>
```

However, that's not pretty readable, you would rather like to use the alternative EL operator `and` for this (see also [operators in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html) for an overview of all available operators in EL):

```
<h:outputText value="#{(sel.description !=null) and (sel.description !='') ? sel.description : 'Empty description'} - "/>
```

All with all, this is in turn pretty clumsy as there's a simpler `empty` keyword for the purpose of testing both nullness and emptiness. This can in your particular case be used as:

```
<h:outputText value="#{not empty sel.description ? sel.description : 'Empty description'} - "/>
```

or

```
<h:outputText value="#{!empty sel.description ? sel.description : 'Empty description'} - "/>
```

or

```
<h:outputText value="#{empty sel.description ? 'Empty description' : sel.description} - "/>
```

Comment: Wow, great explanation. &amp;&amp; worked for me, but I decided to go with 'and' instead, for readability. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

Use `and` instead of `&&`. You simply have XML syntax error.

Comment: @user1820620 it's not just about making it work, instead learning how the technology works.